# Empty search redirect to Home page

Tags: search, views

I am using Drupal 7 and my `search functionality` is not working properly.

When I click on search button without enter any `keyword` it redirects to `home page` with showing the message `Please enter some keywords`. and same thing happens when there is `no result` found for the respective `search keyword`.

So can anyone please guide me how can I redirect the empty search to search page?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I had the same problem right after adding the search block to the front page. Clearing cashes solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_search_results.
 */
function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_search_results(&$variables){
  $results = $variables['results'];
  if(count($results) == 0){
    drupal_goto('<front>');
  }
}
```